# How to run oak-run console on postgres server

Tags: java, postgresql, jackrabbit-oak

I am trying to connect to my DocumentNodeStore in a postgresql database.
Following the instruction from here https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/features/oak-run-nodestore-connection-options.html

```
export CLASSPATH=postgresql-42.2.5.jar:oak-run-1.9.9.jar
java org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.run.Main console jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb --rdbjdbcuser myuser --rdbjdbcpasswd mypassword
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Apache Jackrabbit Oak 1.9.9
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.DocumentStoreException: trying to create datasource org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.rdb.RDBDataSourceFactory.forJdbcUrl(RDBDataSourceFactory.java:90)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.rdb.RDBDataSourceFactory.forJdbcUrl(RDBDataSourceFactory.java:100)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.run.cli.DocumentFixtureProvider.configureDocumentMk(DocumentFixtureProvider.java:117)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.run.cli.NodeStoreFixtureProvider.create(NodeStoreFixtureProvider.java:70)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.run.cli.NodeStoreFixtureProvider.create(NodeStoreFixtureProvider.java:49)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.console.Console.main(Console.java:49)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.run.ConsoleCommand.execute(ConsoleCommand.java:27)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.run.Main.main(Main.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.rdb.RDBDataSourceFactory.forJdbcUrl(RDBDataSourceFactory.java:74)
    ... 7 more
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the link:

```
Note that the oak-run JAR file lacks several RDB specific JAR files that need to be added to the classpath:

1. tomcat-jdbc-8.5.*.jar (Apache Tomcat JDBC connection pool)
2. juli-6.0.*.jar (Apache Tomcat Logger)
3. Whatever JDBC driver is needed to connect to the database
```

I missed out the first 2 jars

Comment: See also <https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OAK-8341>; these have been added in the meantime. Also note that Oak 1.9.* are unstable releases which aren't updated anymore. You should switch to the latest 1.10.* release.